# building dynamic urls in Karate and writing json output to a file

Tags: json, rest, karate

How to build dynamic urls in Karate feature file? I tried something like this and didn't work.

```
Feature: PMS API Status Check
  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * def spirit = 'SANRS'

  Scenario: Get guest details.
    Given path "'#(spirit)'/reservation/all"
```

Url is not evaluating to SANRS and goes as spirit. Also how do I change write the json response to a file. I see we can read the file using read(fileName) but did not see examples for writing to a file.

Answer (score 2):

The `'#(foo)'` notation applies only to JSON, XML or the right-hand-side of a match statement.

Please use it like a normal JS expression:

`Given path spirit, 'reservation', 'all'`

Please do look at the documentation and examples !

Yes, there is no example for writing to a file, because this is not recommended for tests. If you really want to do this - just write a custom Java or JavaScript function, refer to the docs for "Calling Java".

Comment: Now the url is evaluating. Thanks Peter. Reason I wanna write it into a file because I ran the tests in my IDE and the response is so huge that I couldn't see or print the response inside the IDE. It would be nice to have the feature built inside the karate. Thanks.

Comment: @ramkris great. 3 answers for you: a) take a look at the `print` keyword, b) take a look at the `configure logPrettyResponse = true` option, c) https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/935029435140489216 (available as a beta version 0.6.1.2)

Comment: @ramkris I forgot to mention, there should be a log file at `target/karate.log` !

Comment: I am already using print keyword but IntelliJ is not showing the entire response because the response is 88K lines. I will explore others in a moment.

Comment: I don't see the log file under target folder after adding  karate.configure('logPrettyResponse', true);

Comment: @ramkris `logPrettyResponse` will just print to the console, but indented. can you please refer to the doc on logging, if you do that you should see a consolidated log file at `target/karate.log`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#logging