# API test | Karate | Syntax Error while using 'read' keyword

Tags: cucumber, karate, web-api-testing

I am trying to use karate for API testing. Since, the requests and responses are very long, I need to use them using a file. However, 'read' keyword is giving me a syntax error:

```
Scenario: read data from a file  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: syntax error: **'def xyz=read('sample.txt')'**, feature: examples/users/users.featu
re, line: 14
        at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberUtils.runStep(CucumberUtils.java:247)
        at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateRuntime.runStep(KarateRuntime.java:80)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
        at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.runChild(Karate.java:134)
        at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.runChild(Karate.java:37)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.run(Karate.java:144)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Any suggestions on what might I be missing?

Comment: It would help if you showed the code that generated this error.

Comment: Feature: sample karate test script    



Scenario: print data into log

* print 'hello'

Scenario: read data from a file

* def temp = 'hello world'
* print temp
* def xyz=read('sample.txt')

Comment: trying to read a simple text file:* def xyz=read('sample.txt')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate is a *little* fussy about white space, which is a good thing in my opinion, because that aspect of code-quality is enforced by default, and you will thank Karate for this when your test-suite size grows. If you use Cucumber-IDE support, this will happen automatically anyway.

So please surround the `=` with white space and you should be fine.

```
* def xyz = read('sample.txt')
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked. any clue how to 'write' into a file?

Comment: there is deliberately no support for writing to a file, you should never need this. you can achieve this if really needed, refer to this answer and comments for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47515880/143475